# Splitting words with full stops into separate character spans including full stops

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently splitting a word into separate character spans like so:

```
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml11 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
```

However this is missing out the full stops on the words. How could I include full stops in the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g` to `/([^\x00-\x80]|\w|\.)/g` this.

In regex, full stops should be escaped like `\.` if you're passing it as an expression or `\\.` if you're passing it as string to regex builder.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml11 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w|\.)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
console.log(textWrapper.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="ml11"><div class="letters">Hello There. good bye. glag to see you.</div></div>
```